# Builder 2010 "is not accessible" error

Tags: c++, c++builder, c++builder-2010, c++builder-6

I'm trying to migrate my project from C++ Builder 6 to C++ Builder 2010. There is a TChart in the project. And when I compile it in BCB 2010, I getting many errors like `E2247 '_fastcall TSeriesPointer::ChangeStyle(TSeriesPointerStyle)' is not accessible`. What can it be?

There is string with failed code:

```
Series8->Pointer->ChangeStyle(InpStr.ToInt());
```

Series8 -- it's an object of TSeries type.
InpStr -- is an UnicodeString object.

Comment: It's `private` or `protected`?

Comment: If this is purely from migrating between compilers, could any compiler macro mess up the accessiblity between those versions?

Comment: Either way you want to see `TSeriesPointer` definition to see if `ChangeStyle` is declared private/protected instead of public

Comment: I can't find neither TChart API nor source. So I can't say, protected it or private.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer. In Builder C++ 2010, functions with names beginning `Change` is changed to properties without "Change".
i.e:

```
Series13->Pointer->ChangeStyle(4);
```

to:

```
Series13->Pointer->Style = psCross;
```